# Class com.test.test.LibraryBook does not define a no-argument constructor

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I get the following error `Class com.test.test.LibraryBook does not define a no-argument constructor`

Here's my code:

```
  override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.children.count() > 0) {
                        for (eventSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                            val lb = eventSnapshot.getValue(LibraryBook::class.java)
                            lb?.let {
                                val id = lb.id
                                val title = lb.title
                                val image = lb.image
```

Here's LibraryBook Data class

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class LibraryBook(val id: String,
                       val title: String = "",
                       var image: String = "",
                       var subtitle: String = "",
                       var author: String = "",
                       var desc: String = "",
                       var uploadDate: Long = 0,
                       var starCount: Long = 0)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: id doesn't have a default value, have you tried adding one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin did not generate a no-argument constructor for `LibraryBook`, because it still has one required `id` argument.  You will have to make that argument optional as well using some default value, just like the other arguments.